# Cannot consume endpoint at AWS compute instance?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am running an AWS compute instance and have the following script. How do I fire this execution as simply making a GET request to the server didn't accomplish anything?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
       // config
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.write(result)
        });
    })

    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: What does *"didn't accomplish anything"* mean?

Comment: Didn't invoke a method call (for the http request).

Comment: Please explain in greater detail what you tried (EG did you send a cURL request?  To what URL and port?)  Also explain what output you received when you tried it.

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous JavaScript: res.end() executes before your DB connection is established.